# How to add different video effect in android?

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I want to add different video effect in android. The video effect like B&W, Sepia and Grayscale. Can anyone suggest me how to add this effect to video?

Comment: can you share some code if you done it !

Comment: I have used FFmpeg commands for apply filter on video, but I am also not getting proper solution other than these three filters. for Black&White use this command commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf hue=s=0 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097152 -s 320x240 -r 30 /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";
 and more details please refer http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: thank you for your ans. let me try that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eq`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) and [`colorchannelmixer`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer) filters to achieve this. For an instance you can add sepia effect using `colorchannelmixer` like this.

```
colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131
```

Use `eq` filter to adjust brightness, contrast, etc features of the source.
FFmpeg `filter_complex` can be used to associate those two filters if needed. For further information read the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html) and this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/926617/ffmpeg-applying-effects-to-a-video).

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks it's working nice, Can you tell me how to use colorchannelmixer for another filter i.e. Pistachio, Blush, Mauve, Corn, Gamagic, Monochrome, Haze, Blaze, Peppers.

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/926617/ffmpeg-applying-effects-to-a-video). You have to find the color and property values for each effect and use them according to the answers in the above link.

Comment: Can you give me one example for Mauve filter.

Comment: You can try [`eq`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) filter for this. I found that filter [here](http://www.99colors.net/name/mauve) and it just have to change color values only. `eq=1:0:1:1:((224/256)*10):((176/256)*10:((255/256)*10)):1`

Comment: This is eq parameter value but what about the colorchannelmixer parameter value for Mauve filter.

Comment: just keep them to there default values according to the documentation mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I have created two new filters i.e. Pistachio (eq=1:0:1:1:5.7:7.6:4.4:1) and Blush (eq=eq=1:0:1:1:8.6:3.6:5.1:1), and colorchannelmixer used as it is like sepia filter. Is it sufficient to create a new filter or need any changes in eq or colorchannelmixer value?

Comment: for the filters that contains sepia, you need to get `colorchannelmixer` for sepia matrix and to adjust the brightness and other properties you need to chain this with `eq` by making each color to their default in `eq`. if sepia is not specified you can directly use `eq` to adjust color and other properties. keep-in-mind that there are many other filters in FFmpeg to do the same in different way. read the doc.

Comment: I have read the doc for FFMPEG color filter, but I am confused for how to adjust eq value for different color. That's why I have sent you two color eq value can I use as it is or need any changes. Please give me example with this two color also Pistachio and Blush .